# Do Multiple JVM running on a multicore CPU block each other?

Tags: java, concurrency

I may be naive in asking this question but i didn't found any useful answer for this.
Question : How multiple JVM/Java process (having their own thread pool) running on a multicore cpu share the resources? Do individual threadpools use resources equally or they block each other i.e. threads from different pool block each other?

Comment: Two JVMs running on a machine are two distinct processes. So what they have to do with each other is the same as what *any* two processes have to do with each other.

Comment: https://coderanch.com/t/606969/java/JVM-Instances, for reference

Comment: @ernest_k So it means the thread pools hosted in separate JVM can use resource equally? I mean i was looking for idea on : Should we consider this while putting a process on a box already hosting some applications (with no increase in cpu cores) without considering the thread pool capacity of other applications?

Comment: @sjana my question is about resource availability for threads inside different pool.

Comment: pretty good question. While this certainly depends on OS and resourcehandling if it is about the possibility in general I'd say yes, they may(!) block each other if a process is able block a resource(lock exclusive). For a better(real answer) I think you need to be more specific.

Comment: Also think: namespaces/processgroups and (fat) virtualization and resource assignment.

Comment: @kai lets assume i have a unix box(with 8 cores) running a single java process with 8 threads(in pool). If i add another java process on same box again with 8 threads ...should i consider existing process threads while deciding the performance of my current application? like a generic formula of using N+1 threads for N cores will suffice?

Comment: This is now a different question. While multiple threads in one process share  the same processresources, if distributed in two processes, they can't. So in general the resourceallocation is different -  but that doesn't necessarily mean they are blocking each other.

Comment: And then again OS sometimes optimizes resources even cross processboundaries. Eg if two processes have the same memory pages, they are not duplicated and  respective distinct memorypages are combined again if possible.(if they are equal there is no leak of information between the processes so they can be shared without security impact)

Comment: What you do in practice: set up a box, put some monitoring on the box and look at the behavior. And for good numbers while monitoring look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory

Comment: How two distinct processes share resources is up to the operating system. Java thread pools are not a shareable resource. You should let the operating system worry about scheduling. And resource allocation. Don't think you can out-think it.

Answer (score 0):

No differently than any program blocking any other program.  All programs share time doing stuff on your CPU according to the task scheduler in the kernel.